# I have two same example from Python why one is one of them is having syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example 1 - this code is in one line, once I run this code it shows error.

```
print('Hello world') ''
```

Example 2 - here I enter the apostrophe in next line and it is showing no error. Why?

```
print('Hello world') 
''
```

Example 1 came as error
Example 2 printed the code.
what is the logic behind it?

Comment: You can't have e.g. `123 456` (two integer values) directly afterward either. What would something like that even mean?

Comment: Expression separator in python is `;` or `newline` not `space`.

Answer (score 1):

A *statement* is a single block of Python code which does a single 'thing'. Generally, it is a single line of code, but it may span multiple lines, if you use brackets or an intended block. In some cases, multiple statements can also go on the same line if you separate them with a semicolon.

An *expression* is a block of code which evaluates to a single value. A literal value such as `""` or `5` is an expression. A function call such as `sum(a)` is an expression. Expressions can be nested within each other.

You can think of statements as having two types:

1. A statement with a single **expression** such as:

   ```py
   print("Hello, World!")
   ```
2. A special case, such as an **if statement** or **assignment statement**:

   ```py
   a = 5
   ```

If you create a statement which does not fit either of these two templates, then Python will throw an error.

---

In your first example, there are two expressions on the same line.

Because there is no newline, colon or semicolon separating them, the expressions form one statement.

The two expressions are:

- `print('Hello world')` which evaluates to `None` (as well as displaying some output)
- `''` which is a literal and evaluates to the empty string.

The problem is, there is no way to connect these two expressions into one as they are not separated by an operator.

So you are left with two different expressions in a statement, which does not fit either template. Therefore, Python throws an error.

---

Your second example has two expressions, but they are separated by a newline so Python treats them as two different statements. This code runs fine; the second line just does nothing.